# Update a field in Object with nested array by using arrow function

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

My Object nested array is following way,

```
const values: any = {
    name: '',
    type: undefined,
    references: [
      {
        origin: {
          x1: true,
          x2: '',
          x3: undefined,
        },
      },
      {
        origin: {
          x1: true,
          x2: '',
          x3: undefined,
        },
      },
      {
        origin: {
          x1: true,
          x2: '',
          x3: undefined,
        },
      },
    ],
  };
```

I want to update x3 field with references array index, How can I achieve this by using ES6 arrow function. I wrote a function but It doesn't work for me. It would be great if someone can correct my function,

```
 export const replaceReferenceIndex = (values: any) => {
    return {
      ...values,
      references: values.references.map((reference.origin: any, x3: number) => ({
        ...reference.origin,
        x3,
      })),
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to rewrite you `map`'s callback function:

```js
const values = {
    name: '',
    type: undefined,
    references: [
        {
            origin: {
                x1: true,
                x2: '',
                x3: undefined,
            },
        },
        {
            origin: {
                x1: true,
                x2: '',
                x3: undefined,
            },
        },
            {
            origin: {
                x1: true,
                x2: '',
                x3: undefined,
            },
        },
    ],
};
  
const replaceReferenceIndex = (values) => ({
    ...values,
    references: values.references.map((ref, idx) => ({
        ...ref,
        origin: { ...ref.origin, x3: idx }
    })),
});      

console.log(replaceReferenceIndex(values))
```

I have omitted type annotations since you're obviously don't use them for checking correctness.